# Typesafe cast in generic

Tags: java, generics

I have a question around the topic Generics in Java:
Let's say I have following generic (static) method in class. In this method, I want to have access to certain method/fields of the real class. Is there some typesafe way in the static language Java? Or are there any workarounds?

```
public class GenericClassUtil {

public static <T> void  workWithRealTypeAttr(T objectClass) {
//here get access to values of Easel, Cat, Dog or some other class
}

}
```

### In main code:

```
GenericClassUtil.workWithRealTypeAttr(new Easel());
GenericClassUtil.workWithRealTypeAttr(new Cat());
GenericClassUtil.workWithRealTypeAttr(new Dog());
```

Comment: Why not letting Easel, cat, dog implement the same interface and expose those 'certain methods' there?

Comment: return type is not mentioned. Where is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an Interface and extend `Easel`, `Cat`, `Dog` class to that interface.

```
public static <T extends ThatInterface>  workWithRealTypeAttr(T objectClass) {
//here get access to values of Easel, Cat, Dog or some other class
}
```

[Ref:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html)

> There may be times when you want to restrict the types that can be used as type arguments in a parameterized type. For example, a method that operates on numbers might only want to accept instances of Number or its subclasses. This is what *bounded type parameters* are for.
>
> To declare a bounded type parameter, list the type parameter's name, followed by the extends keyword, followed by its upper bound, which in this example is Number. Note that, in this context, extends is used in a general sense to mean either "extends" (as in classes) or "implements" (as in interfaces).

```
public class Box<T> {

    private T t;          

    public void set(T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    public T get() {
        return t;
    }

    public <U extends Number> void inspect(U u){
        System.out.println("T: " + t.getClass().getName());
        System.out.println("U: " + u.getClass().getName());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Box<Integer> integerBox = new Box<Integer>();
        integerBox.set(new Integer(10));
        integerBox.inspect("some text"); // error: this is still String!
    }
}
```

Comment: why Generic is needed in this case? Simply use `ThatInterface` as method arguments.

Comment: if you have interfaces that extend from the interface, then this is necessary in order to use both types of the interface. This gave me a headache a while ago.

Comment: @Higune So `ThatInterface` contains methods specific to Bird as well as Mammal ,how? Interface should be designed for one functionality, You don't want to mix `Flyable` and `Swim-able` in one interface.

Comment: @Higune  How to call methods of **real class**? In this case you need to define all the methods in one interface and all the classes must provide implementation of all the methods, not relevant as well for example you need to implement Bird specific method in Mammal class as well that's not a good design.

Answer (score 1):

You can do if you limit the generic type to classes that extend a certain base class.

For example if your method only operates on `Animal` class then you would have:

```
public static <T extends Animal>  workWithRealTypeAttr(T objectClass) {
   objectClass.someAnimalMethod()
}

public class Animal {

    public void someAnimalMethod() {

    } 
}
```

Each one of `Easel`, `Cat` and `Dog` would have to extend `Animal`. Trying to call `workWithRealTypeAttr` with an argument that does not extend `Animal` would result in a **compile** time error.

You can of course offer yourself even more flexibility by using interfaces instead of classes. Generics would work in exactly the same way.

You would just have an interface `Animal` and the classes `Easel`, `Cat` and `Dog` would implement that interface.

**NOTE**

As @user3218114 very correctly points out, there is no need to use generics in this simple case. You can just go with `Animal` as an argument to `workWithRealTypeAttr`. But I did not post that answer because I wanted to show OP how generics can work in the case he/she presented. The solution would obviously be more applicable if the method worked on Collection or something else that could take full advantage of generics.

Comment: what `Gerenic` will do here. Simply pass `Animal` as method arguments.

Comment: You are correct of course, but what I was trying to show is how you can generally work with generics in the fashion that the OP wants. If I just used the `Animal` class or interface, OP would not get the understand generics like he is trying to

Comment: I will add a note to the answer.

Comment: We can further groups animals as suggested in my post because Animal is more generic class that don't have all the methods specific to bird and mammal.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to have access to certain method/fields of the real class

If you want to access method/fields of the real class then use different **overloaded methods**

```
class GenericClassUtil {

    public static void workWithRealTypeAttr(Bird objectClass) {
          // call a method specific to Bird (Easel)
    }
    
    public static void workWithRealTypeAttr(Mammal objectClass) {
     // call a method specific to Mammal (Cat, Dog etc)
    }
}
```

You can groups classes as Mammal, Bird and make the method more generic.

[image]

---

You can group classes based on behavior as per design pattern.

```
class GenericClassUtil {

    public static void workWithRealTypeAttr(Flyable objectClass) {
          // call a method specific to Flyable 
    }
    
    public static void workWithRealTypeAttr(Swimmable objectClass) {
     // call a method specific to Swimmable 
    }
} 

interface Swimmable { public void swim() }
interface Flyable   { public void fly()  }
```

[image]

It's better explained in [Head First Design Pattern](http://uet.vnu.edu.vn/%7Echauttm/e-books/java/Head-First-Java-2nd-edition.pdf)

Comment: This feels similar to the Visitor pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not elegant you could use construction as below. You can try using instanceof and casting.

```
public static <T>  workWithRealTypeAttr(T objectClass) {
    if (objectClass instanceof Easel) {
        ((Easel) objectClass).toSomehtingEaselsDo());
    } elseif (objectClass instanceof Cat) {
        ((Cat) objectClass).toSomehtingCatsDo());
    } elseif (objectClass instanceof Dog) {
        ((Dog) objectClass).toSomehtingDogsDo());
    } else {
        //do something to inform about not supported class.
    }
}
```

The other way may be using a common interface (as suggested in other answers) `<T extends yourInterface>` or a Decorator pattern.

Comment: this looks really bad.

Comment: I know it's not elegant. But it works. Plus in question a 'class specyfic methods' where requested, so using common interface is not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can do is let all your classes implements a common interface and keep one common method in that interface.

And you have to specify bounds for your T like   (Considering Animal is the super class for all your mentioned class)

Then you can access t.commonMethod() inside

For example 
Have interface like

```
public interface Animal {
    void commonMethod();
}
```

Inside your method

```
<T extends Animal> tryWithGenerics(T t) {
    t.commonMethod(): //call like this
}
```

**Note :**
All your classes should implement that Animal interface

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

There are two (or more) ways to achieve it.

You can use Animal interface/class and use wildcard like this:

```
public static <T extends Animal> void makeAnimalEat(T animal) {
    animal.eat();
}
```

or use reflection like this:

```
public static <T> void makeAnimalEatReflection(T animal) throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
    animal.getClass().getMethod("eat").invoke(animal);
}
```

Where Animal is interface:

```
interface Animal{
    void eat();
}
```

For additional information about generic and wildcards you can visit http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html